# ocamlnet : how to install nettls-gnutls?

Tags: ocaml, gnutls

I spent a hard time trying to install nettls-gnutls library of ocamlnet ([ocamlnet-gnutls](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/dl/ocamlnet-4.0.1/doc/html-main/Tls.html)) - but in vain - I am not able to find how to install it.
I have both tried with ocaml 4.03.0 and 4.02.1.
My aim is to use Nettls_gnutls.init() in my code.

I installed ocamlnet & confgnutls: opam install ocamlnet & opam install conf-gnutls. Is there any other install to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the fresh install:

```
$ opam switch 4.04.0
$ eval `opam config env`
$ opam install conf-gnutls
```

If some system packages are missing, resolve them:

```
$ opam depext conf-gnutls.1
```

And, finally, install ocamlnet:

```
$ opam install ocamlnet
```

Testing:

```
$ ocaml
# #use "topfind";;
# #require "nettls-gnutls";;
# Nettls_gnutls.init();;
- : unit = ()
```

What step from the above causes You a problem?

Comment: Thx! now to answer to your question : I believe I mixed some stuffs. It is also working with 4.02.1 & 4.03.0...

Comment: Thanks to You, I've noticed that 4.04 is out :)